# undefined props in React ES6

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to use props similar to a tutorial I found online but I am getting an undefined error as shown all the way at the bottom. Is there any way to fix this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import PACK_OF_CARDS from '../utils/packOfCards'

import shuffleArray from '../utils/shuffleArray'

import io from 'socket.io-client'

import queryString from 'query-string'

let socket

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000"

const Game = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const data = queryString.parse(props.location.search)

    // initialize socket state
    const [room, setRoom] = useState(data.roomCode)
    const [roomFull, setRoomFull] = useState(false)
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
....
```

```
ERROR:
Game.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
    at Game (Game.js:17:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Here is where Game is being called:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import randomCodeGenerator from '../utils/randomCodeGenerator'

const Homepage = () => {
    const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState('')

    return (
        <div className='Homepage'>
            <div className='homepage-menu'>
                <img src={require('../assets/logo.png').default} width='200px' />
                <div className='homepage-form'>
                    <div className='homepage-join'>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Game Code' onChange={(event) => setRoomCode(event.target.value)} />
                        <Link to={`/play?roomCode=${roomCode}`}><button className="game-button green">JOIN GAME</button></Link>
                    </div>
                    <h1>OR</h1>
                    <div className='homepage-create'>
                        <Link to={`/play?roomCode=${randomCodeGenerator(5)}`}><button className="game-button orange">CREATE GAME</button></Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Homepage
```

```
import './App.css'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Homepage from './components/Homepage'
import Game from './components/Game'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {/* switch to Homepage */}
        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path='/play' element={<Game />}  />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I am learning off [this](https://github.com/mizanxali/uno-online) GitHub project and my code seems to match theirs but I am getting this error. My thoughts are that it could be an issue with the version of React perhaps? not too sure

Comment: Show where you're using `Game` please

Comment: Please provide the code where you are passing the props in the `Game` component.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to get query params right? if you using router v6 u can get it using `useSearchParams()` find here for more details [link](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/query-strings-search-params-react-router)

Comment: Just included where the Game file is being called as well as the original code base I am following

Comment: did you try <Route path='/play' component={Game}  /> instead of <Route path='/play' element={<Game />}  /> ?

Comment: @omer.ersoy I am using React router v6 which doesn't support that and requires me to do  <Route path='/play' element={<Game />} />

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are not passing anything to the Game component as props. Can you confirm that by including a snippet of the way you are using it?

Comment: Just included where the Game file is being called as well as the original code base I am following –